# How do I add a spinner icon to an HLS stream in Google VR view for Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-videoview, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am looking to add a `Spinner` icon in the Google VR view `VideoWidgetView` sample for an *HLS stream*. 
[Google Sample](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/vrview)

Comment: define a relativeLayout and add videoWidgetView and spinner to it!

Comment: I need a spinner to be added to the stream. I am able to set a flag for video onLoad but need one for buffering